# Reading lines from c file and putting the strings into an array

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I'm trying to add each line of a c file into an array. The contents of files.txt is

```
first.c
second.c
third.c
fourth.c
```

I want my code to print each of these lines, add the line to my array, and then print out each entry in my array. Right now it is doing the first part correctly but it is only adding fourth.c to the array. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    int numProgs=0;
    char* programs[50];
    char line[50];

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("files.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL) {
        //check to be sure reading correctly
        printf("%s", line);
        //add each filename into array of programs
        programs[i]=line; 
        i++;
        //count number of programs in file
        numProgs++;
    }

    //check to be sure going into array correctly 
    for (int j=0 ; j<numProgs+1; j++) {
        printf("\n%s", programs[j]);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did u mean `sizeof(line)` ?

Comment: @gargankit `sizeof line` is correct also.

Comment: This line: programs[i]=line; will not work for two reasons.  1) the array of 50 pointers to char needs to have the needed allocation of the memory (and setting of the pointer to that memory) for each of those 50 pointers.  Suggest you use calloc() so the memory segments will be pre set to all '\0'.  2) all this line is doing is setting the programs[i] pointer to point to the array line[].  What is really needed is something like: strcpy( programs[i], line );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```
programs[i]=line;
```

to

```
programs[i]=strdup(line);
```

Otherwise all pointers in the `programs` array will point to the same location (that is `line`).

BTW: if *files.txt* contains more than 50 lines, you will run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

1. No need for `i` there and to save all pointers to lines in array you must use `strdup()`. Just do like that:

   `programs[numProgs++] = strdup(line);`
2. In the second loop condition must be `j < numProgs`.
3. Add additional condition to your while loop to prevent writing pass the end of array:

   `while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL && numProgs < 50)`

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate new storage for each line, otherwise you only have 1 line buffer to store the file names so only the last one shows up, do this in the while loop:

```
programs[i] = calloc(strlen(line)+1, 1);
strcpy(programs[i], line);
```

Answer (score 0):

when declaring `char *programs[50]` are not valid pointers. So you have allocate memory for every pointer based on every line size. So, try this one.. (Here i am using malloc & strcpy)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    int numProgs=0;
    char* programs[50];
    char line[50];

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("files.txt", "r");

   while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)!=NULL) {
   //check to be sure reading correctly
    printf("%s", line);
    //add each filename into array of programs
    programs[i]=malloc(sizeof(line));
    strcpy(programs[i],line);
    i++;
   //count number of programs in file
    numProgs++;
  }

  //check to be sure going into array correctly 
  for (int j=0 ; j<numProgs+1; j++) {
  printf("\n%s", programs[j]);
 }

 fclose(file);
 return 0;
}
```